# Ordenamiento de listas C#

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, linq

tengo una duda sobre el manejo de listas ordenadas en C#

básicamente tengo una lista como la siguiente

```
1/02/2018      Capital    $800
1/02/2018      Interes    $1000
1/02/2018      IVA        $160
1/03/2018      Capital    $800
1/03/2018      Interes    $1000
1/03/2018      IVA        $160
```

Me gustaría poder retornar la lista de la siguiente forma, ordenada por fechas

```
Fecha      capital     interes     iva
1/02/2018   $800        $1000       $160
1/03/2018   $800        $1000       $160
```

únicamente utilizando sql link

Alguna idea?

Saludos y gracias

Comment: coloca el codigo de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 2):

La manera mas sencilla de ordernar una lista es usando linq es a travez del método `OrderBy` para ordernar de manera ascendente o `OrderByDescending` para ordenar de manera decendente.

Por ejemplo:

```
miLista = miLista.OrderBy(x => x.Fecha ).Tolist();
```

o

```
miLista = miLista.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fecha ).Tolist();
```

Adicionalmente puedes usar el método `Reverse` para invertir el orden de tu lista.

```
miLista = miLista.OrderBy(x => x.Fecha ).Reverse().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución que buscas es la siguiente en donde hago un agrupamiento por fecha.

```
    private void listar()
    {
        List<Datos> list = new List<Datos>();

        list.Add(new Datos() { fecha = "1/02/2018", name = "Capital", valor = "$800" });
        list.Add(new Datos() { fecha = "1/02/2018", name = "Interes", valor = "$1000" });
        list.Add(new Datos() { fecha = "1/02/2018", name = "IVA", valor = "$160" });
        list.Add(new Datos() { fecha = "1/03/2018", name = "Capital", valor = "$800" });
        list.Add(new Datos() { fecha = "1/03/2018", name = "Interes", valor = "$1000" });
        list.Add(new Datos() { fecha = "1/03/2018", name = "IVA", valor = "$160" });

        var results = from x in list
                      group new { x.name,x.valor} by   x.fecha;

    }    
    public class Datos
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string fecha { get; set; }
        public string valor { get; set; }

    }
```